# Oracle SQL request date input and ouput day

Tags: sql, date, input, output

I need to write a query which will output day of inputed date in format DD.MM.YYYY. If format is any other there must be no output. Like this:

```
Enter value for anydate: 15.02.1996

DAY
________
THURSDAY
```

Comment: I have tried to use DEFINE with no luck, maybe you can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `select datename(dw,YOUR_DATE_HERE)`, this should give you the day of week

Comment: This is what I get:

SQL> SELECT DATENAME(DW,&ANYDATE);
Enter value for anydate: 15.02.1996
old   1: SELECT DATENAME(DW,&ANYDATE)
new   1: SELECT DATENAME(DW,15.02.1996)
SELECT DATENAME(DW,15.02.1996)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Try using `TO_DATE('15.02.1996', 'DD.MM.YYYY')`